# How to evenly bake a daquoise disk?

Tags: baking, macarons

I plan do make a Daquoise. I've seen people making them round, consisting of 2-3 disks, piped like so:

[image]

Once I tried to bake a Macaron this big and failed because while the outer area where done, the center was still pretty undercooked, I wasn't even able to lift the Macaron from the sheet.

In my oven, I used top & bottom heat.

As Macaron and Daquoise batter is pretty similar, I am afraid to fail again. Is there anything I can do to bake such a disk (about 18cm diameter) evenly? Or would you recommend to make it square shaped?

Comment: I believe the main issue is not so much the shape of the daquoise, but the time and temperature:  you want to bake it very slowly, at a low temperature.

Answer (score 3):

A dacquoise isn't so much baked as it is dried. Usually this is done for an hour or more at a temperature below 300F. If you have problems with the top drying too quickly and leaving the bottom unset, you can get a simple spray bottle and mist the top with water toward the beginning of the baking time to slow it down. Also, I notice that the picture is using a silpat, I don't know if that was just for illustration, but while silpats are wonderful, they do tend to slow the cooking on the underside of whatever is on them.

Comment: Sour, that is clearly an exopat, not a silpat! :-)  Although I own both and don't see any difference in performance....

Comment: Thanks for that answer! The Exopat image (thanks SAJ14SAJ ;-) was just for illustration. Using a spray bottle seems a bit experimental for me, but actually it sounds like a good idea. But then again, how do I determine when the Daquoise is done when using  this method? Probably just testing every few minutes?

Comment: Once it gets to a point where you think it should be done, you should be able to get away with gently lifting it with a spatula and touching the bottom to see if it's dry. The weight will also give you a feel for how dry it is. You can also crank the heat up for the last few minutes to brown it a smidge and be sure. Not strictly traditional, but I can't be the only one who prefers a bit of color on my meringues...